# SQL: filtering data to map the trajectories that are followed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, sequence

I want like to filter the data so that only these rows are kept that show the sequencing of locations for each ID. Any idea how I can accomplish this with SQL?  Note that the same location can return multiple times, but I want to map each subsequent change in location (i.e. the trajectories).

I do not know how to generate the sequencing column (based on Location) as depicted here, nor how to obtain the desired result below. See:

[image]

Does anyone knows how to accomplish this in SQL Server?

Thanx

Comment: What version of SQL?

Comment: Also, please don't use pictures of your data. If you provide copyable examples, it's much easier for people to help.

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework? Your SEQUENCE column is probably:

```
 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) AS 'SEQUENCE'
```

...and the derived table can be assembled with simple GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

Comment: Hi, dense_rank won't do the trick. What I'd like to achieve is for my denserank column to increment every time there is a change in the value of Location (even if the value itself is reused). See the sequence column for what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

The query is like:

SELECT ID, Location, Date, Location FROM DataSet WHERE ID in (‘123456’,’654321’) ORDER BY ID, Date

But do not know how to get column Sequence (or Desired Result).

DATA

```
ID  Date    Sales   Location    Sequence
123456  1/01/2018   5   E313    1
123456  1/01/2018   40  D412    2
123456  1/01/2018   54  D412    2
123456  4/01/2018   15  A122    3
123456  5/01/2018   45  A122    3
123456  7/01/2018   36  A122    3
123456  7/01/2018   23  D412    4
123456  8/01/2018   12  D412    4
654321  1/01/2018   5   E313    1
654321  2/01/2018   17  E313    1
654321  3/01/2018   16  D412    2
654321  4/01/2018   15  E313    3
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
ID  Location            
123456  E313            
123456  D412            
123456  A122            
123456  D412            
654321  E313            
654321  D412            
654321  E313
```